# Drupal 8 Ckeditor: How to provide wrapper element for more than one element?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I have implemented inline styles as well as block element styles in ckeditor from configuration. But when I apply wrapper element on multiple elements, it gets applied on each item individually.

e.g

```
<p class="wrapper">some text here</p>
<ul class="wrapper">list here</ul>
```

Whereas, I want to have a wrapper element like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
element#1
element#2
Elements@3
</div>
```

Do let me know if it doesn't make sense.

Thanks.

Comment: I asked this question here as well: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221679/drupal-8-custom-styles-in-ckeditor-not-wokring-for-multiple-elements

Comment: i'm not ure but maybe you need to edit ckeditor json config file

Comment: I figured it out You have to create ckeditor plugin first and then add that plugin as drupal module. This is the only way